# How to invoke a Python server script from a client URL

Tags: python, sqlite, server

I am a C/Objective-C/Swift developer, mostly for mobile platforms.

I've done a little PHP server-side work, but very little.

I'm hiring my son (who's a sophomore in college studying CS) as a junior developer to do some server-side work for a client project I'm working on (for iOS and Mac). He knows Python fairly well, but hasn't done server work with it before.

(This is a custom app that will issue formatted HTTP GET and POST requests, not a web interface.)

Since he knows Python, and the consensus I've seen on the net is that Python is a cleaner, more modern language than PHP, we're going to use Python, not PHP, for the server scripting language.

Thus I'm doing a little digging on his behalf.

When I need to invoke a PHP script on the server, I might use a URL like this:

```
http://domain/path/script_name.php?key=value
```

On the server, this invokes the script script_name.php at the specified path, and passes it the URL.

Do you use the same technique with Python scripts?

Would sending the URL

```
http://domain/path/script_name.pyc?key=value
```

Do the same thing? (Invoke the python script and pass it the URL)

Is there any configuration you need to do server-side in order to invoke your Python script with a client-side URL?

And what tools/libraries do you recommend to support the Python development?

The server will be a Mac running OS X server, connected to an SQLite database. It will be responding to requests from the client by looking up records in the SQL database and returning them in JSON, and accepting posts from the client, also formatted in JSON.

This is a pretty low-volume application, so performance of a simple Python script should be adequate (a couple of dozen client apps, with fairly low traffic.)

After doing a little more digging, I found FastCGI and mod_wsgi. It sounds like mod_wsgi is a good fit for my needs.

Comment: You can write CGI scripts in Python using the [`cgi`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/cgi.html). Of course you have to configure your webserver to execute such a script. But I'd recommend a library like [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Requests is a *client* library which something completely different.

Comment: But why would you want to use CGI?

Comment: @James_Parsons Of course you don't want to use CGI. But the whole question is off-topic because it is asking for a library and is a too broad "how do I write a web application in Python"-question.

Comment: I'm not asking how to write a web application in Python. My question is specific and focused. "How do I invoke a specific python script from a client-side URL."

Comment: Why not cgi? https://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/running-your-first-cgi-program-with-apache2/

Comment: @DuncanC : the point is: Python is a general programming language not an embedded server-page language like PHP and there are _many_ ways to use Python to serve HTTP requests - from apache/cgi (don't) to full blown pure-python HTTP servers. So yes, your question really is either "how do I write a web application in Python" (too broad) or "which framework should I use" (off topic).

Comment: If you are willing to use mod_wsgi you can write a very simple WSGI application with no framework. http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2007/5/21/getting-started-with-wsgi/ you will however need to make sure all your routing is performed by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually going to expand my comment to an answer as it is the simplest way in Python.

You will need a WSGI server: mod_wsgi, Gunicorn, uWSGI, CherryPy, etc...

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return 'Hello world!'
```

This will return "Hello world!" to the browser when you hit the WSGI server so long as you have configured it to point to this application.

This is the easiest way to run Python on the web. However it is advised to use a framework such as Flask, Bottle, Django, etc... It will cover a lot of edge cases and allow you to route requests and lots of other lovely things.